# When to withdraw other faculty applications: conditional offer letter or contract?

Tags: job-search, job, faculty-application, contract

I've heard one should let search committees know when you've accepted another offer.  What is the right time to do that?

If I have an offer letter that is conditional on getting a work visa (which I think should be no problem), and I accept this offer, should I wait until I actually sign the contract?

This would probably mean putting several departments through the entire interview process with almost no chance of my actually accepting an offer.

Comment: Are any of your other options ones that won't require a visa?

Answer (score 4):

Normally you should not withdraw your applications until you have received a binding job offer that you intend to sign.  If you are delaying signing it, that does not matter.

Depending on your circumstances, an offer conditional on a visa may be extremely risky.  Visa risk is unusually high right now owing to the pandemic, but even before the pandemic I have known people to wait for more than a year for a visa.

Comment: The risk mostly depends on the country in which the university is located. In Europe, visa issues might delay the process by many months, but there's usually no risk that the visa might not be granted (for a university-level job). In North America, one large country was pretty unpredictable until recently, but will probably be more predictable in the next four years.